# Recoding missing binomial variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data

I have the following varibles:

```
variable1 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1); 
variable2 = c(1,0,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,0,0,NA,NA,1); 
variable3 = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1)
```

I need to recode var2 and var3, so that when var1=0 then var2 and var3 = 0 (are not missing).
Can I do it using if/else syntax in R?

Comment: Can you show the expected output to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. try this:

```
var2 <- ifelse(variable1 == 0,
               0,
               variable2)
var3 <- ifelse(variable1 == 0,
               0,
               variable3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to wusel's answer, here are a couple of ways to address this that are more typically seen.

**Simply fill the NA values without using `ifelse`:**

```
variable2[is.na(variable2)] <- 0
variable3[is.na(variable3)] <- 0
```

**Index based on `variable1` without the `ifelse`:**

```
variable2[variable1 == 0] <- 0
variable3[variable1 == 0] <- 0
```